# How to create field calculator expression in a joined table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, loop

I want to calculate values within a field for a table (tableE) based on values of the field of another table (tableS) and within a loop:

Basically I create two lists of tables: table_EMISS and table_SURF and make the calculations for one table of each list giving certain matching conditions.

Finally I want to match the result table to a raster and create a new raster based on values of the calculated field of the table.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
#total emissions per country:
path = r"G:\new_scenario\new_table"
table_EMISS = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    arcpy.env.workspace = root
    files = arcpy.ListTables("emiss*")
    for fichero in files:
        table_EMISS.append(os.path.join(root, fichero))
table_SURF = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    arcpy.env.workspace = root
    files = arcpy.ListTables("total*")
    for fichero in files:
        (nombreFichero, extension) = os.path.splitext(fichero)
        table_SURF.append(os.path.join(root, fichero))
countries_RAS = "G:\\model_run\\countries"

#calculate one raster for each land use with calculated values of emissions
for tabE in table_EMISS:
    for tabS in table_SURF:
        if tabE[-6:-4] == tabS[-10:-8]: #join only tables with the same conditions
            arcpy.JoinField_management (tabE, "cou_abb", tabS, "cou_abb", "SUM")
            arcpy.AddField_management (tabE, "emiss_" + tabE[-6:-4], "DOUBLE")
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(tabE, "emiss_" + tabE[-6:-4], "!" + tabE [-12:-4] + ".Emissions!" * 1000000 / "!" + "!"+ tabE [-12:-4] + ".SUM!", "PYTHON", "#")
            arcpy.JoinField_management (countries_RAS, "cou_abb", tabE, "!" + tabE + "." + "cou_abb", tabE[-6:-4] + "2015")
            outLook = Lookup(countries_RAS, "!" + tabE [-12:-4] + "." + tabE[-6:-4] + "!")
            outLook.save(path + "\\emiss_" + data[3:] + ras [-8:-4])
            arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(countries_RAS, tabE)
```

I get stuck in the calculation of the new field getting this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

I don't know if I'm not using the right expression to call fields: i.e.

> "!" + tabE [-12:-4] + ".Emissions!"

refers to the name of the table (deleting the path and the extension of the file)

Comment: You've got a great deal of extraneous information in this question, yet it's missing necessary details (the exact contents of the expression and the types of the fields). If you construct a code snippet that isolates the problem, and search on the error message, you might find the problem resolves itself.

Comment: I agree with Vince. Try to focus on main issue without giving us "extra" info we don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions Vince. I managed to find the solution myself, the problem was that the multiplication was getting as inputs a string and a number, so I just adjusted everything to be read as a string:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(tabE, "emiss_" + tabE[-6:-4], "!" + "Emissions!" + "* 1000000 / !SUM!", "PYTHON", "#")
```

and this way everything run fine